# show script in mobile only in blogger blog

Tags: mobile, blogger, blogspot

I have a script that need to work only in mobile view in my blog in blogger (blogspot). How can I do it?

This is the script:

```
<!-- Beginning PassBack for Ad unit KartisimOnline_Android_MobileWeb_Transition_IP ### size: [[1,1]] -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
    googletag.pubads().definePassback('7047/KartisimOnline_Android_MobileWeb_Transition_IP', [[1,1]]).display();
</script>
```

the template is responsive.

Tx for anyone that can help....

Answer (score 1):

You only need to put your script inside this conditional.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobileRequest'>
    ...
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this one:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.isMobile == &quot;true&quot;'>

....Your script here....

</b:if>
```